# Usando Fetch Async/Await para cargar paginas internas con Javascript

Tags: javascript, fetch, async

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio practico para probar mis habilidades en Javascript en FETCH combinado con Async/ Await. El trabajo consiste en que a traves de la pagina principal se pueda acceder a las demás paginas sin necesidad de abrir otra pestaña sino que en la misma pagina cargue (Como si de un TAB se tratara).

**Ya lo realice** sin embargo no se si pueda optimizar de alguna manera, intente haciendo un método aparte que pudiera recibir las opciones y no colocarlo directamente en el try pero no pude. Agradezco sus comentarios.

**Las paginas las tengo guardadas en una carpeta llamada assets, solamente tiene un texto , una imagen y un titulo diferente.**

**El main**

```html
<header>
 <div class="header-content container">
 <div class="logo">
        <img src="img/kEnAi.svg" alt="" class="nav-logo">
 </div>
<nav class="main-nav">
 <ul class="list">
  <li class="items"><a href="assets/home.html" class="link">Home</a></li>
  <li class="items"><a href="assets/acerca.html" class="link">Acerca</a></li>
  <li class="items"><a href="assets/servicios.html" class="link">Servicios</a></li>
  <li class="items"><a href="assets/contacto.html" class="link">Contacto</a></li>
</ul> 
</div>
</header>

<main class="container"></main>
<footer class="footer container">
    <small>Footer prueba</small>
</footer>
```

**SCRIPT**

```javascript
const d = document;
const $main = d.querySelector("main");

//CARGO LA PAGINA PRINCIPAL DEL MAIN
d.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",getHTML);

// METODO PARA CARGAR LA PAGINA PRINCIPAL
const getHTML = async () => {
try {
    let res = await fetch("assets/home.html");
    let data = await res.text();
    if(!res.ok) throw {status:res,statusText:res.statusText};
    console.log(data);
    $main.innerHTML = data;
} catch (error) {
  console.log(err);
  let message = err.statusText || "Ocurrio un error";
} finally{
    console.log("Mensaje prueba");
}
}

//METODO PARA CARGAR LA PAGINA DEPENDIENDO DE LA OPCION QUE ESCOJA
d.addEventListener('click',async e=> {
if(e.target.matches(".link")){
    e.preventDefault();
    try{  
      let options = {
          method: "GET",
          headers: {
              "Content-type": "text/html; charset=utf-8"
          },  
      }, 
      res = await fetch(`${e.target.href}`),
      data = await res.text();
      if(!res.ok) throw {status:res.status,statusText:res.statusText};
      $main.innerHTML = data;
    } catch (err){
        let message = err.statusText || "Ocurrio un error";
        console.log(message);
    }
}
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo necesitas una función para cargar cualquier página, recibiendo la URL como parámetro y, al escuchar clics en el documento, verifica que se trata de un enlace, propiedad `.tagName` y que contiene la clase deseada `.classList.contains('nombre-de-clase')` para ejecutar la misma función.

```
const d = document;
const main = d.querySelector("main");

// Método para cargar cualquier página
const getHTML = async (url) => {
    console.log(url);
    try {
        let res = await fetch(url);
        // Aquí es donde deberías revisar res.ok, antes de obtener los datos
        if(!res.ok) {
            throw {status: res.status, statusText: res.statusText};
        }
        let data = await res.text();
        main.innerHTML = data;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('Error:', err);
        let message = err.statusText || "Ocurrio un error";
    }
}

// Obtener contenido de página principal al cargar el dom
d.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => getHTML('assets/home.html'));

// Escuchar clics en documento y analizar para cargar contenido
d.addEventListener('click', e => {
    // Verificar que se trata de un enlace y tiene la clase link
    if(e.target.tagName == 'A' && e.target.classList.contains('link')) {
        // Cancelar evento
        e.preventDefault();
        // Cargar contenido, enviando solo URL del enlace
        getHTML(e.target.href);
    }
});
```

Comment: Sabia que se podia acortar mas pero nunca espere que fuera tanto!!!muchisimas gracias por la ayuda !!